# custom typescript definitions not working on windows 10

Tags: windows, typescript, vue.js, typescript-typings

I have a Vue 2.x CLI based project that runs with typescript and vue class components. Here I want to use a package called vueisotope that has no type definition file. To make it work with typescript I changed my tsconfig.json to alternatively search for .d.ts files inside a 'customTypes' folder. I also created a customTypes/vueisotope/index.d.ts file and declared the module. On Ubuntu the project works well but on Windows 10 I still get the following error:

```
15:24 Could not find a declaration file for module 'vueisotope'. 'node_modules/vueisotope/dist/vue_isotope.min.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try npm install @types/vueisotope if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing declare module 'vueisotope';
```

I also tried to reference the file as an ambient module but that also doesn't work:

```js
/// <reference path = "../customTypes/vueisotope/index.d.ts" />
```

Am I doing something wrong here or is it a Windows/TypeScript/IDE issue? How can I bring that to work on a Windows machine?

My tsconfig:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./customTypes",
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "customTypes"
  ]
}
```

my index.d.ts:

```js
declare module "vueisotope" {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I simply didn't understand the `typeRoots` part correctly. I also had to define vueisotope inside the `types` part.
So the working tsconfig would be:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./customTypes",
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "vueisotope",
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "customTypes"
  ]
}
```